# Modifying data in a csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to open and modify data in a csv file. I am trying to learn to utilize the csv module and I have little experience with it.

Basically what I am attempting to accomplish is have the program open a csv, it then opens a second csv to compare the data in column 0, from the first csv, with a matrix of sort in the second csv. If the data in a row of column 0 matches the second csv file's row/column 0 it will take the data from column 1, in the second csv, and replace it in the original csv file.

I was able to accomplish this without using the csv module with the code below.

```
file = open("needs_convertedTest.csv","r")

newFile = []


for line in file:
    data = line.split(",")
    file2 = open("options.csv","r")
    for choice in file2:
        dataOption = choice.split(",")
        if dataOption[0] in data[0]:
            docType = dataOption[1].strip("\n")
            newLine = "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s" %(docType,data[1],data[2],data[3],
                                                     data[4],data[5],data[7],data[6],data[8])
            newFile.append(newLine)



file = open("needs_convertedTest.csv","w")

for line in newFile:
    file.write(line)



file.close()
```

The problem with using this code is that there are a couple of document types that are similar in name and for some reason the program creates a double of one of them, as demonstrated below.

```
MTG Closing | Margarett Jackson | 123-45-6789 | 1410000625 | 111814 | 18    | G:\Downloads\Exports\Images\Loan_1410000625\Good Faith Estimate.pdf | 16
MTG Closing | Margarett Jackson | 123-45-6789 | 1410000625 | 111814 | 18 | G:\Downloads\Exports\Images\Loan_1410000625\Acknowledgement of Receipt of Good Faith Estimate.pdf | 16
MTG Disclosures | Margarett Jackson | 123-45-6789 | 1410000625 | 111814 | 18 | G:\Downloads\Exports\Images\Loan_1410000625\Acknowledgement of Receipt of Good Faith Estimate.pdf | 16
```

The first and third lines are correct. The second one is a duplicate of the third but has an incorrect Document Type, MTG Closing.

The options.csv file is formatted like this.

```
MTG Closings | Good Faith Estimate
MTG Disclosures | Acknowledgement of Receipt of Good Faith Estimate
```

This is followed by several other rows containing similar data that the program uses to make comparisons and replacements of data in the needs_converted.csv file.

This program only deals with the information in data[0] which is the first column.

This is the program I wrote attempting to perform the same task, utilizing the csv module.

```
import csv

newFile=[]

with open('needs_converted.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    data = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                        quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    with open('options.csv','r',) as csvfile2:
        dataOption = csv.reader(csvfile2, delimiter=' ',
                        quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        next(reader,None)
        if dataOption[0] in data[0]:
            docType = dataOption[1].strip("\n")
            newLine = "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s" %(docType,data[1],data[2],data[3],
                                                     data[4],data[5],data[7],data[6],data[8])
            newFile.append(newLine)
```

If someone could help me construct the code to accomplish this via the csv module, I would be really grateful!

Thanks,
Max

Comment: If you do things like that frequently, you really want to check out [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) if you have not done so yet.

Comment: Im very open to using pandas, however I am not familiar enough with it. Would you be able to help me write this section of code utilizing pandas. Or at the very least get me started. I do need help, but I am willing to do the work as well.

Answer (score 0):

It can be tricky to replace a line replace directly in an input file that you're looping over (though we do have a [*fileinput*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#module-fileinput) module that supports an [*inplace*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input) update option).

Instead, it is usually much simpler to build a *new* output file. The [csv module writer objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects) will let you output CSV formatted lines effortlessly.  Once the new file is fully populated, just replace the original file with the new file using [*shutil.move()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move).

Hope this gets you back on the right track :-)

Comment: I was able to get it to work, semi successfully, as shown in my first example. It also does create a new csv file at the end. I do not need it to update the original file. My first example showed it using the same file, however it was just taking the old one and writing over it and basically saving it as a new file.

Comment: Unfortunately I am still struggling with this.